# in JS, are (a===b===c) and ( (a===b)&&(a===c)&&(b===c) ) the same? //sorry for my ignorance

Tags: javascript

My aim is "to execute the code when only a, b, and c are equal".
I figured out two codes:

Code#1:

```
if (a===b===c) {console.log('something')};
```

code#2:

```
if ( (a===b)&&(a===c)&&(b===c) ) {console.log('something')};
```

I have tried both and realized that only "code#2" is able to respond my purpose (execute only when 3 variables are equivalent (eg. `a=b=c`),
But for "code#1", it executes whenever there are 2 equivalent variables (eg. `a=b` or `b=c` ..)

MY QUESTION IS: "what is the difference between code#1 and code#2?"

Comment: What's with the `c` flag?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't mean what you think it means. look up the difference between "=" and "==". Then, in Javascript, "===" will become important.

Comment: code #2 has a redundant comparison: just check `if a == b && b == c` is enough

Comment: Fabrizio: note that he has written `if a = b && b = c` he's doing assignments, not equality comparisons.

Comment: @Almo: And even for `a==b==c`, that *still* won't mean what he (probably) thinks it means.

Comment: From his introductory aim I can suppose he is using `=` in place of `==` @Almo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author doesn't understand what he's asking. The only "correct" answer answers the actual question, but not what I think is the intent of the question.

Comment: Hey Hoppy... you still have more edits to do. You have `a=b` and stuff still in the lower part of the question.

Answer (score 8):

The question you're actually asking is whether these two are the same:

```
if (a === b === c) {...}
if ((a === b) && (b === c) && (a === c)) {...}
```

Shortly, they're not. The first can be summarized as:

```
if ((a === b) === c) {...}
```

Which, if a and b are equal, evaluates to

```
if (true === c) {...}
```

Which is not the same as checking if all three are equal.
To check three-ways equality, you will have to manually check all sides:

```
if ((a === b) && (b === c)) {...}
```

Comment: Note that `===` is transitive, so `(a === b) && (b === c)` is enough

Comment: @Cimbali Good point, I didn't think about that and blindly followed the style the question proposed.

Comment: how many ways can i assign for declaring that a , b ,and c are not equal?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're asking? You can create countless combinations of logical operations if you so desire.

Comment: (a==(b==c)) means a , b and c are equal. What if i want a, b and c not to be equal, how many ways can I code?

Answer (score 2):

I will try to explain the difference. Explain of first code example:

```
if (a=b=c) {console.log('something')};
// Code above means: if (c) {console.log('something')};
// So if Boolean(c) is false, console.log will not work
```

Explain of second example:

```
if ( (a=b)&&(a=c)&&(b=c) ) {console.log('something')};
// Code above means: if (b && c && c) {console.log('something')};
// So if Boolean(c) or Boolean(b) is false, console.log will not work
```

An assignment operator assigns a value to its left operand based on the value of its right operand and return the value of its right operand.

Comment: Ok, he's finally edited the question to mean what we thought he meant. So this answer isn't what he was looking for anymore. Good try though. :)

Answer (score 2):

Time for a truth table... The final two columns are the expressions you're comparing

```
A       | B     | C     | A == B    | (A == B) == C | A == B && B == C
--------+-------+-------+-----------+---------------+-----------------
TRUE    | TRUE  | TRUE  | TRUE      | TRUE          | TRUE
TRUE    | TRUE  | FALSE | TRUE      | FALSE         | FALSE
TRUE    | FALSE | TRUE  | FALSE     | FALSE         | FALSE
TRUE    | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE     | TRUE          | FALSE
FALSE   | TRUE  | TRUE  | FALSE     | FALSE         | FALSE
FALSE   | TRUE  | FALSE | FALSE     | TRUE          | FALSE
FALSE   | FALSE | TRUE  | TRUE      | TRUE          | FALSE
FALSE   | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE      | FALSE         | TRUE
```

Nope! They're not the same.